# Question on App Store Review Guidelines

Tags: uitextfield, app-store, placeholder

In Apple new release "App Store Review Guidelines" http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html I am confused with section 3.2 that stated "**Apps with placeholder text will be rejected**". Does it means app should NOT use the **placeholder** property of UITextField?

Thanks.

Comment: No. That's not what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It basically refers to unnecessary text in the app's description that is meant to draw in a broader range of searches.

Comment: Thanks seanny94 for the clarification. Actually, I also doubt my own question as it would be illogical that Apple will reject app that use UITextField's placeholder property which is part of Apple's own standard API.

Comment: Done seanny94. Sorry I forgot to do it before.