# Load HTML on UITableView's Cell with Custom Font

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am working on one application where I need to load HTML content on Cell of UITableView, also I need to show this content using Custom Font.

Main issue in this approach is performance Because of HTML content it takes time.

How do I load HTML on webView which is inside then UITableView ?
How do I use custom font to represent the custom HTML content ?

I have use then UITextView to load the HTML. It was fast and good approach but now it's undocumented method so at the time of app upload I am getting warning of undocumented method.

Finally, I want the Data representation like iQuran application URL of application https://itunes.apple.com/id/app/iquran-lite/id285944183?mt=8

The screen shot of iQuran Lite app

[image]

This is data representation that I want in TableView I am getting this content in HTML!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: "How do I use custom font to represent the custom HTML content" - there's a `font-family` CSS property you can use.

Comment: please take a look..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695466/question-on-app-store-review-guidelines

Answer (score 3):

Using a UIWebview inside a UITableviewCell is not a good idea. The HTML will only start rendering when the cell is visible. For a short moment you will see an empty cell. This does not look good. Can't you just use a label with a custom font? You could try this: https://github.com/JPluto/FontLabel

Comment: I have HTML content so I can't use it.

Comment: Then maybe you could try creating a html table in one full screen UIWebview instead of using a UITableView

Comment: this correct that `uiwebview` shows empty `cell` for few mili seconds. Will give `FontLabel` a try.

Answer (score 1):

try `CoreText` framework

Use this code: https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";
[myUIWebView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: this solution is surly working for single UIWebview but When WebView will be in UITableView's cell. It became problematic for app performance

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
[myWeb loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:justify; font-size:45px;font-family:HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold;color:#0000;'>%@",postHTML] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: The closing `</div>` tag is missing.

Comment: this solution is surly working for single UIWebview but When WebView will be in UITableView's cell. It became problematic for app performance as well as Content have different hight

Comment: @DVL Performance? For 128 bytes of text, seriously? Also, if somebody puts `UIWebView`s in a table view, he even deserves getting bad performance.

Comment: @DVL did you profile the app? Or just an unproven claim? Parsing a string format and creating a new NSString is probably the least of your performance problems.